# Pandas sorting concatenated series: speed up slicing by date

Tags: pandas, slice

I have two pandas series indexed by dates as follows, with about 40m elements in pd_series, and s1 is a sorted subarray of pd_series with about 20m elements.  I am trying to avoid sorting the whole of pd_series by doing the following.

```
s1 = pd_dc_series
s2 = pd_series[dt_dc_end+2:dt_end]
s = pd.concat([s1, s2])
s.sort()
```

Where pd_dc_series and pd_series are pandas series, and dt_dc_end and dt_end are pandas.tslib.Timestamp objects and there are about 20m dates between and including them.  However, the `s2 = pd_series[dt_dc_end+2:dt_end]` slicing step takes 6.29239106178 seconds.  Is there some way to greatly speed this up?